# how to get the values based on selection of Input Controls values

Tags: report, jasperserver

Hi I have 3 Input COntrols say Car, Bike and Vehicles and Cars contain list as Hyundai,Maruthi,Audi and Bikes Contain Honda,suzuki,Bajaj and Vehicles Input Control contain Cars and Bikes as a dropdown 
Scenario 1:when Hyundai is selected in car and Honda is selected in Bike and Car is selected in Vehicles 
Report should run by Vehicles and must shows list all the drop down related to car and the same vice versa when Bike is selected in Vehcile
 I have created 3 Parameters $P{Cars},$P{Bikes}&$P{Vehicles}
when $P{cars==Hyundai}&&$P{Bike==Honda} and $P{Vechiles==Car} the above equation is not working
(Please adjust with my English)

Comment: Please read [ask] and [edit] your question accordingly. This is not a free coding service. You'll have to write the code yourself, and you can ask for help about specific problems with *your* code.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the parameter syntax wrong: When you say $P{cars==Hyundai} you are passing NO expression but instead, you are calling a parameter with name "cars==Hyundai"

The way to go is

```
$P{cars} == "Hyundai" or $P{cars}.equals("Hyundai")
```